# TIdTCPServer - On unexpected disconnect wait for reconnect

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-6

I have several programs made using Delphi 6 with Indy components and am trying to figure out a way to put a TCP connection on hold in case of an unforeseen disconnect.

We connect via TCP  to PLC's on our factory floor and for whatever reason (operator messing with things they shouldn't be, switches going down temporarily, faulty wire, or whatever the case may be) the connection is ended.

This causes our programs to lock up hard. As soon as a disconnect happens between PLC and PC, the program will linger for a short amount of time and finally lock up.

Is there a way to put the connection on hold when a disconnect between PLC and PC happens, and reestablish connection without locking the program up?

Perhaps also is there a way to do this with `TIdTCPClient` as well?

If I need to be more descriptive please say so and I will try to be.

```
procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AThread: TIdPeerThread);
var
  i : Integer;
begin

begin
if NOT  IdTCPServer1.Active   then exit;
try

   Comm_Status  :=  True;

 {************************************************
    Clear PC Buffer before Read
  ************************************************}
 for i := 0 to giBufferSize -1 do  begin
     gabToPCBuffer[i] := 0;
 end;

 {************************************************
            Recieve the buffer from PLC
  ************************************************}
    // WE READ
     AThread.Connection.ReadBuffer(gabToPCBuffer, giBufferSize);

     StateMachineLogic;      //Sort Through buffer and copy to server buffer

     // WE SEND back to PLC
     AThread.Connection.WriteBuffer(gabToPLCBuffer, giBufferToPLC );





except
    //;
end;
end;
end;
```

Comment: Please show some code. Where does the TIdTCPClient code 'linger', is it running read / write socket operations in a loop? Does your code suppress exceptions of Indy socket operations (using empty except blocks)?

Comment: Currently I am having the most problems with IdTCPServer faulting out when a disconnect happens. With IdTCPClient I am just looking for information as we do not use it much but have plans to. The connection is constantly passing a buffer back and forth between PLC and PC, as far as I know there is no suppressing of exceptions. The code I can pull up is extremely basic but it is the almost identical to what we do everywhere.

Comment: You did update the indy components to the most recent indy9 (or better, 10) ?  The components that come with D6 are iirc not SMP safe.

Comment: No this version of delphi is almost bone stock besides some components for serial. We do have Delphi 7(bone stock as well) and XE3 but for the program we are currently having a problem it was made in Delphi 6. I am sure we could probably recompile in delphi 7 or XE3(hope don't have to)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a client connection to a TCP server is gracefully disconnected from the client, the OnDisconnect event will be triggered. Your thread will also be marked terminated, so you should check for this in your loop.

However, for non-graceful disconnections, the TCP server will immediately error on the next read or write. You have wrapped your read and write in an empty `try...except` block. Instead, you should handle the error and break out of the loop.

For Delphi 6, you should update your Indy components to the latest Indy v9 release.

Comment: Will have to try this, sort of newer to programming network connections and I am left to figure this one out. I appreciate the help! Once I break out of the loop I guess I would be able to wait for the connection to reestablish itself? or would I still have to close and reopen the program? (Hope this question is not too dumb)

Comment: @Ralre, typcially, you just exit the OnExecute, and let the client establish another connection.

Comment: Awesome, will try this out as soon as I can! I really appreciate the help!

Comment: A better solution, and how `TIdTCPServer` is meant to be used, is for you to get rid of the `try/except` altogether and let `TIdTCPServer` handle any exceptions that are raised. If you need to do something when an uncaught exception is raised, you can use the `TIdTCPServer.OnException` event for that. If you must put a `try/except` in the `TIdTCPServer.OnExecute` event, then at least re-raise any `EIdException`-derived exception you catch, let the server handle them.